# Not receiving email and public_profile after facebook login using satellizer.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, facebook-login, satellizer

I am using satellizer.js for facebook login in my website. I am using nodejs server. This is the configuration i am using.

```
 $authProvider.facebook({
        url: '/api/auth/facebook',
        authorizationEndpoint: 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/oauth',
        redirectUri: (window.location.origin || window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host) + '/',
        requiredUrlParams: ['display', 'scope'],
        scope: ['email','public_profile'],
        scopeDelimiter: ',',
        display: 'popup',
        type: '2.0',
        popupOptions: { width: 580, height: 400 }
    });
```

On server side I am receiving as request body:

```
{ code: 'AQD1Sq3TaQ1DF6LfQAHNioPSJfM0t3cOHSO3pbYMZ5TslXYFK4AuRg5eDj7xL0L7YfegaVZj6BQ9f5Zc44wJnQuA2Yfe9rhjoJBRnWL4WUt93o1sy4jwSsN6k2uceE4Yk3L9YkdQZm5TqKpRELeANR8pI_EjW1irqkoh6OUtLltvAujQDp3ChCblti2v4HA1cJQE6EG-0iBia54eUEFkLtkzvDeLi6WZ7I8rRg3Nr_gmUiPmNVDhPgb7fRiUOjeeQ2J-mt1Ai36bJp8Z3dk6UUbA3SMKq0lPkdoAhN8iW-aAaTlI6NQdSBV29Yu2JNwS9Je1obPeFy3KUmTCDeqWug9e',
clientId: '1039213532796449',
redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8001/' }
```

As with satellizer config i am asking for email and basic_profile. Why am I not receiving it on server side?

Answer (score 0):

Problem most likely should be with the server side, you need to update your Graph Api to version 2.5 , and include fields param in Graph Api Url, like this:

```
$graphApiUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=id,name,email,picture,first_name,last_name';
```

For more information take a look at this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5